# Is a Canadian citizen planning to get TN visa considered authorized to work in the USA?

Tags: usa, working-visas, canadian-citizens

I am a Canadian citizen looking for a job in the USA. My plan is to get a job in the USA and *then* apply for a TN visa. Here are my questions:

1. When I apply for jobs in the USA, the employers ask whether I'm authorized to work in the USA. Am I authorized in this situation?
2. Working with a TN visa doesn't require employer sponsorship, does it? (I'm thinking that I'll just need the employment letter to get the visa at the port of entry).

Comment: Welcome to Expats.SE! StackExchange sites are a little different from others on the internet. We try to leave out greetings or "thanks" or "please help", using a writing tone more like a FAQ document. See http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/behavior and the other pages in our help section to learn more. I proposed an edit to your question attempting to make it simpler and clearer. Feel free to reject or roll it back if I messed something up, and make any edits you feel will improve your question, using the "edit" link underneath your question.

Answer (score 5):

No, you're not yet authorized to work in the United States. You could include information about a TN visa in your cover letter.

You are correct that you can apply for the [visa at the border](http://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/tn-nafta-professionals) directly with a [letter](http://www.nafsa.org/_/file/_/amresource/8cfr2146.htm) from your (prospective) employer. The employer alternatively could file form I-129. Then you would present the approved form at the border instead.